# Validation of the provided antiforgery token failed. The cookie token and the request token were swapped

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have create a ASP.Net Core 2 application using `IAntiforgery` apis.

This provides a method to return a cookie which it does.

The client takes that cookie and on subsequent POST requests it puts the value in a X-XSRF-TOKEN header.

Middleware validates this and allows the request to continue or not if it fails.

With the correct cookies and headers sent in the request always fails validation and I don't understand why.

The whole reproduction is here https://github.com/jchannon/AntiForgery

However, the main problem area is below.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IAntiforgery antiforgery, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ValidRequestMW");

            //Don't validate POST for login
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("login"))
            {
                await next();
                return;
            }

            logger.LogInformation(context.Request.Cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]);
            logger.LogInformation(context.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"]);

            //On POST requests it will validate the XSRF header
            if (!await antiforgery.IsRequestValidAsync(context))
            {

                /****************************************************
                 *
                 *
                 * For some reason when the cookie and the header are sent in on the /create POST this validation always fails
                 * 
                 * 
                 ***************************************************/
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                logger.LogError("INVALID XSRF TOKEN");
                return;
            }
            await next();
        });

        app.UseRouter(r =>
        {
            r.MapGet("", async context => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello world"); });

            //This returns a XSRF-TOKEN cookie
            //Client will take this value and add it as a X-XSRF-TOKEN header and POST to /create
            r.MapPost("login", async (context) =>
            {
                antiforgery.SetCookieTokenAndHeader(context);
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            });

            //If XSRF validaiton is correct we should hit this route
            r.MapPost("create", async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 201;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Created");
            });
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLogging(x => x.AddConsole());

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
            options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        });

//        services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieMW")
//                .AddCookie("MyCookieMW", cookieOptions =>
//                {
//                    cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
//                    cookieOptions.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
//                    cookieOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
//                    cookieOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;
//                });

        services.AddRouting();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So after diving into the source code of antiforgery and some badly named methods (`SetCookieTokenAndHeader` I'm looking at you). The correct code should be:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IAntiforgery antiforgery, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ValidRequestMW");

            //Don't validate POST for login
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("login"))
            {
                await next();
                return;
            }

            logger.LogInformation("Request Cookie is " + context.Request.Cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]);
            logger.LogInformation("Request Header is " + context.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"]);

            //On POST requests it will validate the XSRF header
            if (!await antiforgery.IsRequestValidAsync(context))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                logger.LogError("INVALID XSRF TOKEN");
                return;
            }
            await next();
        });

        app.UseRouter(r =>
        {
            r.MapGet("", async context => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello world"); });

            //This returns a XSRF-TOKEN cookie
            //Client will take this value and add it as a X-XSRF-TOKEN header and POST to /create
            r.MapPost("login", async (context) =>
            {
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, 
                    new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            });

            //If XSRF validaiton is correct we should hit this route
            r.MapPost("create", async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 201;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Created");
            });
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IAntiforgeryTokenGenerator, MyTokenGenerator>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAntiforgery, MyAntiforgery>();

        services.AddLogging(x => x.AddConsole());

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyAntiforgery";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        });

        services.AddRouting();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the problem with your code, as I just discovered in my app, is that services.AddAntiforgery creates its own cookie with the csrf secret that it uses to validate against the actual token. This is called the Double Submit Cookie approach, and it makes sense since the csrf secret isn't stored in the session like they do it in other frameworks