# Configure ASP.Net Core Antiforgery to work with Angular SPA

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

How do you configure ASP.Net Core web Application to provide anti-forgery tokens to Angular application?

Answer (score 3):

I spent a not insignificant amount of time trying to piece this together, so this is my attempt to help others trying to figure out how to get anti-forgery tokens working with ASP.Net Core 6 and Angular.

First of all, out-of-the-box, Angular handles passing authentication tokens to the server API with every POST request. You don't need to anything other than ensure that a cookie called `XSRF-TOKEN` is sent to the client when the application first connects to the server. All of the configuration will be inside your ASP.Net Core Web application

In your API application, you need to do a little setup to make this happen. Open your `Program.cs` file and add the Antiforgery service to the application:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
});
```

The Antiforgery service is responsible for creating tokens and helping your verify that the tokens received back from the client are valid.

Now that you've setup the service, you need to generate the cookie and sent it to the client. In order to do that, we need to setup the Request-Response middleware to send the cookie whenever the client requests the starting point of the application. That might be requesting the default.html page if your Angular application and API are both hosted on the same website, or, if your Angular application is hosted on another site, calling an endpoint that isn't protected (like `/api/Login`) to get the cookie.

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();

var service = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var path = context.Request.Path;
    if (path.Equals("/default.html", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // generate .AspNetCore.Antiforgery authentication cookie
        var tokenSet = service.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    }

    await next(context);
});
```

At this point, the only cookie that is sent to the client is the default `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery-something`, but Angular needs more. We need to update the Request-Response middleware to also send the XSRF-TOKEN cookie whenever the client requests the starting point of the application.

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();

var service = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var path = context.Request.Path;
    if (path.Equals("/default.html", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // generate .AspNetCore.Antiforgery authentication cookie
        var tokenSet = service.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        var token = tokenSet.RequestToken;
        // duplicate the .AspNetCore.Antiforgery authentication and create a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN
        if (token != null)
        {
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", token, new CookieOptions
            {
                Path = "/",
                HttpOnly = false
            });
        }
    }

    await next(context);
});
```

Now you'll see two cookies being sent to the Angular application. Both of these cookies are required for this to work. The `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery-something` cookie contains a secret that is used to validate against the actual token. This is called the Double Submit Cookie approach (Cheers to [OzzyTheGiant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3287514/ozzythegiant) for that useful piece of information from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054376/24856).

Now that all of the plumbing is setup, add `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` attribute to the top of each controller you want to secure. If you want to bypass this for certain endpoints, use `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to decorate those methods.

You are all set. The Angular application will get two cookies on the first request, `XSRF-TOKEN` and `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery-something`. These cookies will be sent back with every request to the server. Additionally, Angular will add an HEADER entry called `X-XSRF-TOKEN` for every `POST` request. The Antiforgery service will compare these values in the `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` logic and throw an expection if the validation fails.